# Visual studio image and text blur on mouse hover

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

My computer is a Razer Blade Pro 2014, you can find the features of it here:
http://www.razerzone.com/store/razer-blade-pro

I needed to install visual studio to code in c++, but every time I use an installer from dreamSpark or VS site, it gets blurry.

This happens on the installer itself and on the program after I install it.
It gets annoying

Link to image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IjmS.png

Here is an picture of the installer... I think what it is doing is zooming in the text that I hover over.. I remembered once, I had my mouse on the x button, and half of the screen just have a really zoomed in X. Another time was the install button...

I downloaded several installation files,

VS 2013 express for windows desktop from dream spark

VS 2012 express for windows 8 from dream spark

VS 2012 Professorial for windows 8 from dream spark

VS Ultimate 2013 with Update 4 from VS site

My computer is running on windows 8.

Any idea what is wrong with my computer? Why is this happening? and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: strange..have you updated your graphics drivers? check with your vendor if they have any updates? try to install them and check

Comment: My graphic drivers is up to date.
GeForce GTX 860M
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700HQ CPU @2.40GHz
16 GB RAM
driver version: 347.88
Windows 8.1